# Tag for neurodegenerative disorders is misspelled

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I just noticed that "neurodegerative-disorders" tag contains a misspelling (should be "neurodegenerative-disorders"). Could a mod fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, thanks for spotting this mistake and informing us. I merged the two tags, the now unused misspelled tag will be automatically removed by the system tomorrow night.

Comment: I did the same thing - we were working around that at the same time :) Let's see what happens!

Comment: @AliceD Seems like it worked :-)